# How to Store and retrieve JavaScript Prototype Object in Cache or MemCache?

Tags: javascript, node.js, caching, memcached, npm

I want to access same JavaScript object in multiple node.js files. Each file will be run independently. I tried with Singleton, But singleton will not suit If we run files independently. So I decided to store my JavaScript prototype Object in Cache, So that we can access it from any node js file. I searched in many websites but I did't find anything related to storing prototype object in cache.

Thanks in advance,

Can anyone please suggest me, to use single JavaScript prototype object in multiple node.js files.

Comment: objects live in a thread, and it sounds like you use more than one thread, which means you can't. look into redis.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But i just want to know, Can we store an object in cache or memcache.

Comment: i don't know what "cache" is, but you could store the object's values in memcache. for js, JSON would be the natural fit for serialization of JS objects, though you will need to JSON-ify the prototype object separately from the instance object.